# GitHub repository, indexing issue in search engine

Tags: github

I am having many repository in my GitHub account but the problem is none of them is getting indexed in search engines.

Please point that what am I doing wrong: is there any special setting for getting indexed in search engines, is there is robot.txt I have to include in my repo?

Ex :

- https://github.com/pranaydutta89/angular-signalr-service
- https://github.com/pranaydutta89/console-logger

Answer (score 0):

Google might index the main README page, but only GitHub would index the actual code content in its [GitHub search](https://github.com/search).

And even then, only the commits of the master branch are indexed anyway (not the commit messages, not the other branches commits: just `master`).
See "[How to search for a commit message in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493853/6309)".

Comment: thanks for answer but even i am copying the whole repo keyword to google, even then also its not pointing to my repo

Comment: @PranayDutta yet, your repo is the first result of https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22AngularJS+service+wrapper+for+SingalR+Hubs%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=wuQcVZKzMoHFUtX_g7gI

Comment: not in india https://www.google.co.in/search?q=AngularJS+service+wrapper+for+SingalR+Hubs&oq=AngularJS+service+wrapper+for+SingalR+Hubs&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.256j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8&safe=active#safe=active&q=AngularJS+service+wrapper+for+SignalR+Hubs

Comment: @PranayDutta and do you have access to google.co.uk?

Comment: @PranayDutta also http://www.quora.com/Why-has-Google-not-indexed-my-blog-properly is a good read

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74323/discussion-between-pranay-dutta-and-vonc).