# Search for commits on a branch other than master branch in github

Tags: github, version-control, branch, github-api, branching-and-merging

Commits present in the master branch of any repository can be obtained by searching for it on github web UI and through [github Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits).
For example when we search for this `d28a36113a206f9f84cc97bc72ff84aa93f87ee8` commit, it shows that this commit resides on my `code-quality-metrics` project on both my owner account and on one another.

But if I search for a commit like `3b3e426deacb2fa94159232a15bbdf1a2d8ff194` which is in a branch other than master branch in my repository (which is not yet merged to `master`) zero results are shown in both the web UI and in the API call.

How do we search for commits that resides on branches other than master from `github search api`?

Comment: So you have a commit id but don't know the repository?

Comment: @osowskit I know the repository but the commit is not in its `master` branch

Comment: If you have the commit, you can access it directly via URL. Ex https://github.com/atom/atom/commit/ed1d0ed303016935c7899a875d8607f8e64ed1f3 what are you expecting from the search results?

Comment: @osowskit yeah that's fine, I know the above mentioned commit is in which repository as it is in my repository, but what if I only have a commit hash and that is a commit hash on a branch other than master in a certain repository. How do I search for that commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2017: As I mentioned in "[How to search for a commit message on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493853/6309)" (and this applies to commit themselves, not just their messages):

Only the `master` branch (or [default branch](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/)) is indexed for search in github.com.

Indexing *all* branches of *all* GitHub repo would result in a search space too big to manage for now.

> How do we search for commits that resides on branches other than master from github search api?

You don't. You would have to clone the repo and search through git commands.

---

2023: [`gh search commits`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_search_commits) uses [**Searching commits**](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-commits), which confirms:

> When you search for commits, only the [default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-branches) of a repository is searched.