# How Github or any other cloud based repository services(Gitlab, Bitbucket) store source code files and directories?

Tags: git, file, github, directory, storage

Do they store the meta data of files and directories in databases and the actual files and directories on the files system of the server instances?

Comment: You can [download](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/)  Gitlab CE (Community Edition) and study their sources (written in Ruby).

Answer (score 5):

It should be in **[bare repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002059/6309)**.
But it depends on the *scale* of the Git repositories server you are talking about.

For instance, **[GitHub is using DGit](https://githubengineering.com/introducing-dgit/)**

> DGit is short for “**Distributed Git.**”
>
> As many readers already know, Git itself is distributed—any copy of a Git repository contains every file, branch, and commit in the project’s entire history.
> DGit uses this property of Git to keep three copies of every repository, on three different servers.
> **The design of DGit keeps repositories fully available without interruption even if one of those servers goes down**. Even in the extreme case that two copies of a repository become unavailable at the same time, the repository remains readable; i.e., fetches, clones, and most of the web UI continue to work.

The point is: you cannot just store the bare repo without dealing with the rest:

- authentication (https or ssh)
- authorization (tied to authentication, or also membership)
- diff: as GitHub realizes, you cannot just query a diff from Git and return it. See "[How we made diff pages three times faster](https://githubengineering.com/how-we-made-diff-pages-3x-faster/)".
- search (see "[How to search for a commit message on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493853/6309)"), in `master` branch or in *all* branches: only the `master` branch is supported for now (2017).

And all of this does not even take into account all the services et metadata those hosting servers propose (project, wiki, issues, ...). See for instance "[Moving persistent data out of Redis](https://githubengineering.com/moving-persistent-data-out-of-redis/)" for a glimpse of the kind of technical challenge that poses.

And that is just GitHub. BitBucket and GitLab have their own tehnical challenges and solutions.

Comment: I am working on an app in which I have to store single source code files as well as directories of them. So, I was more interested in the storage mechnism.

Comment: @theleancoder simple git repo: initialize, add and commit on your side, push to an empty bare repo on the server side. It works for code, not databases.