# How to search commit in github

Tags: github

I have the commit hash but want to find that commit in github, I didn't found anyway on github page, anyone know how to do that ?  I mean in github not git.

Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214746/how-to-review-someones-code-given-a-commit-hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply fill in the following URL

```
https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>/commit/<HASH>
```